# Rails - hidden field of double nested form for multiple file upload causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a double nested form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, html: { class: "create-item-form" } do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "item name" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "How do users earn this item?" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tag suggestions (these will help users find your item)" %>
  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_items do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :foo, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "bar" } %>

    <%= user_item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_item_images do |user_item_images_builder| %>
      <%= user_item_images_builder.input :foo, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "bar" } %>
      <%= user_item_images_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false,
                error: false, label: "Pictures of you earning this item",
                input_html: { multiple: true,
                              name: "item[user_items_attributes][0][user_item_images_attributes][][picture]" } %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item request', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

With create action:

```
  def create
    @item = item.new item_params
    raise 'foo'
    @item.user_items.first.user_id = current_user.id
    if @item.save
      redirect_to items_path, notice: "Thank you for your item request!""
    else

      render :new
    end
  end
```

and new action:

```
 def new
    @item = Item.new
    @user_item = @item.user_items.build
    @user_item.user_item_images.build
  end
```

and strong_params

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :tag_list, user_items_attributes: [user_item_images_attributes: [:user_item_id, :picture]]).merge(created_by: current_user.id)
end
```

When I add multiple files and submit the form in development I just get a blank page but in the server console I get this error.

> ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `user_item_images_attributes')

If I remove the second hidden field, the form works.  However, when the form fails validation and is rendered again I end up with a file input for every file that was added.  This is the reason for the hidden field to begin.  The first hidden field works well but when it gets to the second nested form it is causing a problem.

UPDATE:

I changed this line

```
<%= user_item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_item_images do |user_item_images_builder| %>
```

to this

```
<%= user_item_builder.simple_fields_for 'user_item[user_item_images_attributes][]', :user_item_images do |user_item_images_builder| %>
```

and it works.  I really have no idea why.  If someone would like to explain and put it in an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: try like : `<%= user_item_images_builder.hidden_field :foo, "bar" %>`

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli isn't this just shorthand for what I already have that is causing a problem?